# Using the results from a query in BOTH the templates and the view

Tags: django, templates, view

In Django, I need to query a table to get some details from the database. I need the results BOTH in the views and in ALL of my templates.

Is there a way to only run this query once?

Here is my current setup if I don't use a context processor:

`views.py`:

```
def collect_important_information():
    return SomeModel.objects.filter(parameter=abc)

def homepage(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if information:
        do something
    context = {"information": information}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)

def second_page(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if information:
        do something else
    context = {"information": information}
    return render(request, "second.html", context)

def third_page(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if not information:
        do something
    context = {"information": information}
    return render(request, "third.html", context)

def fourth_page(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    context = {"information": information}
    return render(request, "third.html", context)
```

There is a lot of replication here. I can reduce that by using a [custom context_processor](https://betterprogramming.pub/django-quick-tips-context-processors-da74f887f1fc) to insert the "information" variable into each template. Something like this:

`custom_context_processor.py:`

```
def site(request):
    return { "information": SomeModel.objects.filter(parameter=abc) }
```

This allows me to reduce my `views.py` to this:

```
def collect_important_information():
    return SomeModel.objects.filter(parameter=abc)

def homepage(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if information:
        do something
    return render(request, "index.html")

def second_page(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if information:
        do something else
    return render(request, "second.html")

def third_page(request):
    information = collect_important_information()
    if not information:
        do something
    return render(request, "third.html")

def fourth_page(request):
    return render(request, "fourth.html")
```

My views is much cleaner. However, if I do that I have to run the database query *twice* for many of these requests. Once to obtain the database variables I need inside my views.py function (for some condition that takes place, independent from the template), and a second time in the context processor file.

Is there a way to somehow 'centralize' the query and have it run only once, and still inserting it into the template file AND having it available within the function of the view?

Comment: Why do you have to run the query twice? If you inject it under the same name, it will replace the context variable and since querysets are lazy, it will thus only make the query if you evaluate the queryset, which will (normally) not happen if you override it in the context.

Comment: The code above is very repetitive so I have tried using a custom context processor such as this: https://betterprogramming.pub/django-quick-tips-context-processors-da74f887f1fc - but if I do that, then there is a whole different file where the query runs AND the views file where the same query runs. This would lead to the same query running twice I believe, or am I mistaken?

Comment: it depends what `collect_important_information()` does. If it *only* constructs a queryset, it will not run the query since querysets are lazy and are only evaluated if the data is necessary. Of course if `collect_imporant_information` "consumes" the querysets, then you should look how to make this more lazy.

Comment: I have improved the explanation of the two scenarios (with and without custom context processors) above. In my view, neither of them is optimal and ideally I find a way to call the queryset only once because the exact same data is being evaluated, albeit in two different places. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to somehow 'centralize' the query and have it run only once, and still inserting it into the template file AND having it available within the function of the view?

`QuerySet`s are *lazy* constructing a queryset will *not* make a database request, you make a query to the database if you *consume* the queryset, for example by enumerating over it, calling `str(…)`, `repr(…)` and `len(…)` on it, check its truthiness with `bool(…)` or in an `if`/`elif` clause.

If you thus use a context processor that passes the filtered queryset to the template, and you *do* not use the queryset in a way described above, that will not make a query. Furthermore if the data is passed to the context, it will override the data in the context processor. So you can add it to the context in case you already evaluated it in the view, to prevent making a second database query you thus override this in the context, such that there is no reference to the "other" queryset, and the result is reused.

You need to be careful not to construct a new query if the one is evaluated. For example if `qs` is an evaluated queryset, you should work with `qs` again, if you work with `qs.all()` this will make a new `QuerySet` that will then make a query to the database.